# Adjust alarm time to match clock time in python

Tags: python, time, pygame, clock, alarm

I'm just learning Python, and as one of the basic challenges that were suggested to me by friends I've been working on an alarm clock. I successfully made an alarm clock that played a .wav sound at a predetermined time. Now I've been using Pygame for a GUI, and it all worked great, until I had to set the buttons to adjust the alarm time. See when I compare the alarm time to the clock time, the clock time is in string form, so the alarm time has to be as well. But the buttons are unable to + or - from a string, so I'm kind of stuck. I tried ways of turning it into a string, but everything has been fairly unsuccessful so far. Wondering if anyone here had a suggestion.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path, sys, datetime, time
import os, sys, math
import pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *

main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
data_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, 'data')
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now()
clocktime = currenttime.strftime("%H:%M")
alarmtime = "13:23"
pygame.init()

#Screen and background
width, height = 600, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alarm Clock")
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(data_dir, 'diamondplate.jpg'))
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (width, height))

#Current time
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 250)
text = font.render("%s" % clocktime, True, (255,140,0), (0,0,0))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery - 200

#Alarm time
text2 = font.render("%s" % '00:00', True, (255,140,0), (0,0,0))
text2Rect = text2.get_rect()
text2Rect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
text2Rect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery + 200

#Alarm noise
def alarmsound(file_path=os.path.join(main_dir, 'data', 'boom.wav')):
    pygame.mixer.init(11025)
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file_path)
    channel = sound.play()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)

#Image load function
def load_image(file):
    file = os.path.join(data_dir, file)
    surface = pygame.image.load(file)
    return surface.convert_alpha()

#Hour arrow up
class Hourup(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.groups)
        image = load_image('arrowup.png')
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (85,85))
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomleft = text2Rect.topleft

    def click_check(self,eventpos):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(eventpos):
            pass

    def update(self):
        pass

#Hour arrow down
class Hourdown(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.groups)
        image = load_image('arrowdown.png')
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (85,85))
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = text2Rect.top
        self.rect.left = 159

    def click_check(self,eventpos):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(eventpos):
            pass    

    def update(self):
        pass

#Minute arrow up
class Minuteup(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.groups)
        image = load_image('arrowup.png')
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (85,85))
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomright = (442,414)

    def click_check(self,eventpos):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(eventpos):
            pass

    def update(self):
        pass

#Minute arrow down
class Minutedown(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.groups)
        image = load_image('arrowdown.png')
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (85,85))
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = surface.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomright = text2Rect.topright

    def click_check(self,eventpos):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(eventpos):
            pass

    def update(self):
        pass


#Groups
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
Hourup.groups = allsprites
Hourdown.groups = allsprites
Minutedown.groups = allsprites
Minuteup.groups = allsprites
hourup = Hourup()
hourdown = Hourdown()
minutedown = Minutedown()
minuteup = Minuteup()
clickableobjects = [hourup, hourdown, minutedown, minuteup]

def main():
    while 1:
        currenttime = datetime.datetime.now()
        clocktime = currenttime.strftime("%H:%M")
        screen.blit(background,(0,0))
        text = font.render("%s" % clocktime, True, (255,140,0), (0,0,0))
        text2 = font.render("%s" % alarmtime, True, (255,140,0), (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text,textRect)
        screen.blit(text2,text2Rect)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    for object in clickableobjects:
                        object.click_check(event.pos)

        if clocktime == alarmtime and soundcheck = False:
            alarmsound()
            soundcheck = True
        allsprites.draw(screen)
        allsprites.update()
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `strptime()` which will convert a string to a datetime instance.

see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) for how to properly use it.

Comparing two datetime instances will give you a timedelta instance which you can read about [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/datetime-timedelta.html). Essentially it will give you the difference between the two times to the nearest milisecond.

Learn everything you can about the datetime, time, and calendar modules.  Once you learn those dealing with times and dates in python becomes really easy.